# Moq a method in a parent interface throw Exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following definition

```
public interface I1 {
    Task RunAsync();
}

public abstract class A{
    protected I1 iInstance;
    public A(I1 i){ this.iInstance = i; }
}

public interface I2 : I1 {}

public class B : A {
    public B(I2 i2):base(i2){}

    public async Task Method1(){
       await this.iInstance.RunAsync()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to mock `B.Method1` using moq something like this:

```
 var mockI2 = new Mock<I2>();
 mockI2.Setup(i => i.RunAsync()).Verifyable();

 var binstance = new B(mockI2.Object);
 binstance.Method1();
```

When it reach the line `await this.iInstance.RunAsync()` I can see there is a mock object for `this.iInstance` but the call to `RunAsync` throws Exception with the message

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Looks like the methods was not really mocked, i fear has something to do with hierarchy.
In my frustration I tried to use `CallBase = true`, to `mockI2` don't have to much sense but i tried without change the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you haven't set up your interface mock properly. Remember, your `RunAsync()` method returns a `Task`, so you need to setup your mock to return a `Task`. Here's one way to do it:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    _mockI2.Setup(x => x.RunAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));

    await _bInstance.Method1();

    _mockI2.Verify(x => x.RunAsync(), Times.Once);           
}
```

Doing this sets up your mock to return a completed task. Then, when you verify that it's been called, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your async method now returns `null` but should return awaitable result - `Task`, try configure your async method like this:

```
var mockI2 = new Mock<I2>();
 mockI2.Setup(i => i.RunAsync).Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```